# Does my microcode need to be updated?

Tags: cpu, firmware

[image]

Does anyone know if everything is okay with my microcode? What does it mean when it says ''MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode''? Is something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your microcode with the [spectre/meltdown](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker) checker.
It checks whether there is a newer microcode available for your CPU.

Comment: When i used ''sudo spectre-meltdown-checker.sh'' command it gave me this: https://pastebin.com/b7tyCHWJ

Comment: @Weege so you have an elder CPU Model where Intel did not patch the newer spectre variants any more. Your microcode is as current as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU 540` which is now 12 years old.

There's no up to date microcode for this CPU and you should rely on the kernel software mitigations.

The most serious one is Meltdown which the kernel fully mitigates and others are near impossible to exploit remotely, so there's no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

**Unless :**

- experimenting whatever bug an update would fix;
- being commended to do so for security reasons,

**Never** update the microcode. CPU / BIOS

Maintenance engineers just can't do much regarding microcodes and manufacturers have not much willingness for updates.

This leading to the fact that more than 80% of microcode updates consist in disabling functionalities and degrading performances.

Therefore… if your system works… don't fix it.

Of course, trying to profit from some microcode vulnerability needs a significant investment and an appreciable level of competences.
 Overkill if the target is  browsing the internet via whatever ISP, there are far cheaper ways to steal your credit card number, your email addresses or encrypt your filesystems.

Therefore, if your system is wide opened to hackers, should you really care of needle holes ?

If you actually want to care (since there is no update made available for your chip), then Artem S. Tashkinov's answer rightly points to the way to go :  kernel mitigations.

Handle them with care as, depending on your CPU, some of these kernel mitigations can result in a significant performance drop. (up to 40%).
Review all of them carefully and read the documentation regarding [kernel's command line parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html?highlight=kpti) in order to understand how to enable or disable those you **believe** should be.